# Spring Data JPA query returning Object even though result is null

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a method on my Spring Data repository interface defined like this:

```
@Query("SELECT MAX(e.index) FROM entity e WHERE e.companyId = :companyId AND e.userId = :userId")
public Integer getMaxIndex(@Param("companyId") Long companyId, @Param("userId") Long userId);
```

The calling code looks like this:

```
int currIndex = 0;
Integer maxIndex = userActivityQueueRepository.getMaxIndex(companyId, user.getId());
if (null != maxIndex)
{
    currIndex = maxIndex.intValue() + 1;
}
//else no records exist yet, so currIndex is 0  

//create new records starting at currIndex and incrementing it along the way
```

The problem is that when no records exist yet, it is returning `0` and not `null`. So, my currIndex gets set to `1` instead of `0`. Is there something I'm doing wrong in the JPQL? Is there something I can add to the JPQL so it behaves as I was expecting it would?

I'm using version 1.7.2 of Spring Data JPA with PostreSQL and EclipseLink. I turned on the logging of SQL and  ran the query manually in the database, and it gives the results I expect. I just don't understand why it isn't returning `null` when there are no records.

Comment: Have you tried changing method to return int instead of Integer?

Comment: @JakubKubrynski It just returns 0. I purposely made it an Integer so I could distinguish between no records and the max being 0. I may be missing something, but I don't see how having it return an int would help me at all.

Comment: What is the type of `entity.index`?

Comment: doesn't answer your question but given your code comments, are you sure you don't want to be doing Paging? also any chance that MAX() doesn't return null?

Comment: @Guillermo The index field on my entity is of type `int`. As soon as I saw that, I tried changing it to `Integer`, and now it is working as I expected. Go ahead and post an answer for this, and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MAX function (MIN too) the result type is the type of the field, so to return *null* instead of 0, `entity.index` should be like `Integer`, `Long` but no `int`, `long`

See [this table](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbwa) of the official documentation.